# To compare two strings and remove the same characters from string 1 and print the string 2 using C++

Tags: c++, string

I am a newbie in programing and stuck at a point where I have to compare the two strings using C++: string 1 and string 2 for the same characters and then delete those characters from string 1 and print the string 2. Looking forward for your help. My code goes like this:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string first_string;
    string second_string;
    string::size_type start_position=0;

    cout<<"Please enter the first string: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,first_string);

    cout<<"Please enter the Second string: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, second_string);

    while ( (start_position = second_string.find(first_string, start_position)) != string::npos )
    {
    while ( (start_position = second_string.find(first_string, start_position)) != string::npos )
    {
        second_string.replace( start_position, first_string.size(), "" );
        start_position++;
    }
    }
    cout<<"The Result is as follws: "<<second_string<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Looking forward for your help.

Regards,
Sam

Comment: God I keep missing these tags, I shouldn't be on SO past midnight anymore.

Comment: Wouldn't that just print String 2 as it was in the input if I'm reading this correctly? Since you only modify string1?

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: Yes it prints only string 2 deleting the same characters from string 1

Comment: I have edited the program according to my little knowledge in programing but it is not deleting the duplicate characters from the first string instead it is printing the same second string as entered by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare each char in string2 with all chars of string1. If that char from string2 doesn't match any in string1 then append this char to a new string else continue without appending. Continue this for all chars in string2. Now assign the new string as string1. This uses extra o(n) space but is simpler.

Comment: I have edited the program according to my little knowledge in programing but it is not deleting the duplicate characters from the first string instead it is printing the same second string as entered by user.

Comment: Why do you have two while loops that do the same check? If the first char of string1 is not in string2 then your code will not enter the loops and will just print string2 as it is. Your while conditions are not right. You don't need two loops. You should loop till string2's length. Inside the loop, do the check 
"second_string.find(first_string, start_position)) != string::npos" 
with an if statement and if true, replace.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) to represent your string as an array of characters (or even better begin with an array of characters rather than the string datatype). After you do this write a function to go through each array and compare characters (removing where required), its a bit inefficient but it'll do the job and its simple.